# Recursively prove that two recursively defined sets are the same

Tags: induction, recursion

I am reading MIT's Mathematics for Computer Science, and there is a problem where you're asked to prove that two recursively defined sets are the same. I'm not sure how to go about mutual inclusion with recursively defined sets.

**Here is the problem:**
A and B are sets of strings of matched brackets.
Define A as the smallest set such that:
Base case: $\lambda$, the empty string, is in the set. Constructor cases: 1. $st$ is in A (meaning $s$ concatenate $t$ is in A). 2. [$s$] is in A

Define B as the smallest set such that: Base case: $\lambda$, the empty string, is in the set. Constructor cases: $[s]t$ is in B.

Prove A and B are the same set:

**Here is my attempt:**
Clearly $\lambda$ is in both sets.
Now want to show that anything can be constructed by recursive definition of $A$ can be also constructed with recursive definition of $B$. Suppose $s \in A$, I want to show $[s] \in B$ and $st \in B$.

$[s] \in  B$ since we can let $t=\lambda$ in B, and thus $[s] \in B$. Is this right? It seems like I'm supposing $s$ the same in both sets. I am stuck at how to show $st \in B$.

Comment: What is the difference between $[s]$ and $s$?

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it:

I will prove by structural induction.

Base case: The empty string $\lambda \in A, B$ clearly.

Induction step: Let $x,y \in A$ and $s,t \in B$. Assume that $x$ and $y$ can be constructed by the recursive definition of $B$, and assume that $s$ and $t$ can be constructed using the recursive definition of $A$. We want to show that 1) $xy$ and $[x]$ can be constructed with $[s]t$ for suitable $s$ and $t$, and 2) $[s]t$ can be constructed by $xy$ and $[x]$.

1) Clearly $[x]=[s]\lambda$ for any $s=x$ and $t=\lambda$, so $[x]$ can be constructed with $[s]t$.
Next, $xy=[s']t'y$ where $s', t' \in B$ by the structural induction assumption. Thus take $s=s'$ and $t=t'y$, so $xy$ can be constructed by $[s]t$.

2) [s]t can be constructed by $xy$, by letting $x=[x']$ where $x'=s$ and $y=t$

Thus we have A=B.

Answer (score 0):

Note that all strings are made up of $[$ and $]$ only.

For clarity, call the variables $s, t$ on one side and $x, y$ on the other. As you note, you have to prove both sets of rules give the same *end* results, you are trying to get an *intermediate* result. No wonder it won't work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "intermediate" result? I'm starting with st and [s] which is how elements in A are constructed, and trying to show that I can construct [s]t, which is how an element in B is constructed. Is that not what the end result is?